# Dataframe to table load in Python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am loading data from excel to data frames and then finally to a table in Snowflake in a Python script. While I have been able to load the data frame to the table, it is taking a long time to load. For example, it took me 5 minutes to load 100 records. I have been trying out other ways in which I can load the data but unfortunately, the references I found online have not been working for me. Would appreciate it if you can guide me to a better and more efficient way of doing this.

Code Snippet of how I am loading the table:

df_hdr and df_attrib_values are my dataframes.

```
def insert_dim():
 del_dim = cs.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE util_db.public.TABLE1;")

  for(row,rs) in df_hdr.iterrows():
     COLUMN3 = rs[0]
     COLUMN4 = rs[1]      
     #insert_dim =
     insert_dim = cs.execute("INSERT INTO util_db.public.TBL_DIM_10 VALUES (" + "'" + COLUMN3 + "'" + 
                               "," + "'" \
          + COLUMN4 + "'" + ");")
        
def insert_mstr():
 del_dim = cs.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE util_db.public.TABLE2;")

 for(row,rs) in df_attrib_values.iterrows():
     col1 = str(rs[0])
     col2 = str(int(rs[1])) 
     COLUMN3 = rs[2]
     COLUMN4 = rs[3]
     insert_mstr = cs.execute("INSERT INTO util_db.public.TBL_MSTR_10 VALUES (" + "'" + col1 + "'" + 
                                     "," + "'" \
          + col2 + "'" + "," + "'" + COLUMN3 + "'" + "," + "'" + COLUMN4 + "'" + ");")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of single INSERTs, build one array on Python and use it with a Multi-row INSERT:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#multi-row-insert-using-explicitly-specified-values

So basically, you need to convert your cs.execute to array push, and then run one cs.execute at the end of the function.